# Error while initializing the trace reader

Tags: c#

I get the below error while using `traceReader.InitializeAsReader(connDef, "D:\\trace.tdf");`

**Error:**

> 2013-07-25 13:59:53,578 [8] DEBUG
>   Error
>   while invoking InitializeAsReaderException has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.SqlTraceException: Failed to
>   initialize object as reader. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException    at
>   ?A0xe4daab47.ProcessError(Int32 hr, UInt16* lpszMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceControllerBase.InitSource(Boolean
>   bReOpen)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceObjectsRowsetController.InitSource(Boolean
>   bReOpen)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader(ConnectionInfoBase
>   serverConnInfo, String profileFileName)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader(ConnectionInfoBase
>   serverConnInfo, String profileFileName).

Scenario:

> I use sql 2012 server under windows 2008 R2.

Assemblies loaded are

```
connectionInfoAssembly = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
traceAssembly = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
smoAssembly = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
```

ConnInfo is

```
server='';Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=false --- Database name.
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're logging an error at DEBUG?

Answer (score 2):

> I figured out the issue.

*I use wix tool to create the msi and deploy this project (Trace reader) as service in windows.What was happening is, trace reader service was running with LocalSystem account.This account did not have sufficient privileged to access traces.*

*I have enabled "Alter trace" permission for LocalSystem as below.*
[image]

*This is required when you deploy the project as service.*