# TraceServer class fails to initialize as reader when pointing at local SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, trace, sql-server-profiler

I'm trying to create a trace in .NET via the `TraceServer` class. My code is as follows:

```
var connectionInfo = new SqlConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = @".\sqlexpress",
    DatabaseName = "master",
    UseIntegratedSecurity = true,
};

// note that at this point I can run a simple SELECT query
// using connectionInfo.ConnectionString

var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer();
server.InitializeAsReader(
    connectionInfo,
    @"C:\users\chasemedallion\desktop\trace.tdf"
);

while (server.Read()) {
    Console.WriteLine(server["TextData"]);
}
```

However, `InitializeAsReader` fails with the following exception:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.SqlTraceException: Failed to initialize object as reader. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   at ?A0x97257f7e.ProcessError(Int32 hr, UInt16* lpszMessage)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceControllerBase.InitSource(Boolean bReOpen)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceObjectsRowsetController.InitSource(Boolean bReOpen)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader(ConnectionInfoBase serverConnInfo, String profileFileName)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader(ConnectionInfoBase serverConnInfo, String profileFileName)

What could be causing this? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853114/error-while-initializing-the-trace-reader), but I'm not running as a service and my local account has admin access to the database (I can run traces via SQL Server profiler).

Alternatively, I would be happy with another way of programatically running a trace via .NET. I need to be able to hit local as well as remote servers (like SQL Server profiler does).

Comment: Is Profiler installed on the machine? I don't believe Express on its own includes all of the client utilities and DLLs used for tracing, so you can trace remotely or if the client tools for Developer or some other edition have been installed, but not with Express on its own...

Comment: @AaronBertrand SqlServer profiler is installed on my machine. I routinely use it to profile both the local SqlExpress instance and remote databases. I'd like to do the same thing programattically.

Comment: Does C:\users\chasemedallion\desktop\trace.tdf exist?

Comment: Try and change from AnyCPU to x86 as the TraceServer only works on x86